# Centos Apache Web Application is responding slow

Tags: linux, webserver

In Centos minimal server we have depolyed one application and its running fine at earlier.Now it is taking too much time to load on a browser.I checked Web server httpd logs and it shows error 'googlebot'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You can block the IP address of googlebot.

2) Or you can configure robots.txt file in your document directory.

Check more on https://serverfault.com/questions/201035/how-to-block-googlebot-quickly